# Bytes Array is not Converting to Bitmap

Tags: android, web-services, android-service, android-bitmap

**Here is the image of response**

[image]

**When Services Giving the reposes of imges into bytes**
**bitmap is not converting bytes array**

```
jsonObject= response.getJSONObject("dCafeMenuDisplayMainModel");
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cafeMenuDayList");
                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObjectInner = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //list.add(new cafe_menu("Hellow","Yo Man",""));
                        String title = jsonObjectInner.getString("cafeMenuTitle");
                        String bytes = jsonObjectInner.getString("cafeMenuImage");
                        byte[] data = bytes.getBytes();
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: no bmp gives null .. see the attached picture

Comment: Check for valid base64 String online . It should be corrupted or incomplete . Also add the method in which you are encoding it .

Comment: Because the bytes in bytes.getBytes() doesn't represent a valid bitmap.

Comment: I believe the square braces are also included in the conversion which could be returning you a corrupted/invalid bitmap.